# DAX Command last 30 days data (relative)

Tags: powerbi, dax, days

I am trying to filter data from the table, but I need relative last 30 days from actual date. I am able to get my whole data by this:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUMX(SKzPoh; SKzPoh[PohPMJ x PohKc]);
SKzPoh[RelOP]=2)
```

Can anyone help me please to get data for last 30 days?

---

of course. There is a printscreen of my table. It that enough or do you need more specifications?

File is an .mdb file of inventory management, and the main columns are:

PohPMJ - number of movements

PohKc - value of movement

PohKc x PohPMJ in DAX is just multiply of two values above

Datum - created date of the row in database

RelOP - in db value 1 and 2 (1 for purchase, 2 for sale) so it's a filter there

Thank you

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGnC7.jpg)

Comment: What is your table structure? It helps if you provide some sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Hello, of course. There is a printscreen of my table. It that enough or do you need more specifications?

Comment: Posted it as answer, i am quite new to this portal and didn't find if I can add an image to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this kind of calculation you need to add **DATEADD** as a table filter inside calculate. I have created a dummy table to show how it works

**Sample Table**: Sales

```
Sales = DATATABLE("Date",DATETIME,
                "Sales",INTEGER
                ,{
                            {"2019-01-01",10456},
                            {"2019-01-02",1950},
                            {"2019-01-03",54353},
                            {"2019-01-04",34535},
                            {"2019-01-05",35436},
                            {"2019-01-06",16234},
                            {"2019-01-07",26354}
                }                    
            )
```

Assuming the table is called Sales, the calculation for 5 days relative to each date is:

```
Sales L5 := CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]),DATEADD(Sales[Date],-5,DAY))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like that: CALCULATE(SUMX(SKzPoh; SKzPoh[PohPMJ x PohKc]); SKzPoh[RelOP]=2;DATESINPERIOD(SKzPoh[Datum]; UTCTODAY();-30;DAY)) is right.